# Named scope on the votable object for votes count in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working  on rails 2.3.11 . I am using acts_as_voteable plugin in my rails application.
Blog hasmany votes (votes_for and votes_against) . I kept 2 instance methods for votes_for and votes_against in Vote.rb plugin.
Now i am trying to sort the blogs based on its votes_for
like

```
@blogs = Blog.all(:order => "blogs.votes_for desc")
```

and tried with named scope too

```
named_scope :vote_ups, :order => "blogs.votes_for desc"
```

where votes_for will return the count of all vote up's  to the blog

BUt this is now working
Please give suggestions on this